# Einstein Analytics/Connected App possibly showing logins every 5 seconds in login history for integration user

Tags: einstein-analytics, login, login-history

We have a connected app that we are using for devops that ever since we added it their new dashboard to track devop metrics,  we are seeing login history records every 5 seconds with our integration user account.  I had a ticket with Salesforce and they said it was the datasets in Einstein Analytics & to limit the frequency.   It just doesn't seem right that every time you refresh the dataset that it creates a login record.  Is this normal behavior as it makes using the login history hard?

Thanks for any help anyone can offer.

Comment: Einstein Analytics alleged issue aside, Login History supports list views. You should be able to filter out these logins on the basis of Application and/or Login Type and/or Authentication Method Reference.  (And if none of these criteria can be used to distinguish devops from EA, then you have another issue you should fix)

Comment: Thanks--we set a meeting with the vendor to address,  I will post up the solution once it is determined.   We had 50K logins in a month from this issue which is causing all sorts of reporting issues outside of the list view.  Appreciate your response.